# My App disappeared from play store...Even it's still Published in Developer console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

i have launched my app in play store a month ago , till yesterday everything was fine , it was getting between 50-100 installs per day , and has 8 reviews ... but this morning i tried to find it on the store with all the titles , but no results . like it's hidden or something , but when i logged into my developer console , everything is normal and it's still mentioned as PUBLISHED

Answer (score 1):

This exact thing happened to me at the exact same day, it even affected all of my Android devices which made me a bit nervous. However, I was able to "solve" it by going to "**Settings** -> **Apps** -> **Google Play Store** -> **Storage** -> **Clear data**" on each device and the app would once again be visible on the Play Store.

Hopefully this will work for you as well, if it doesn't you should probably contact Google by going here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing