# Android app no longer available on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I've an Android app that is suddenly no longer available from Google Play.
There was no recent release of a new APK, and the app's Release dashboard says the latest APK is 100% rolled out.

Also, the App Availability flag is "Publish".

Does anyone know what's causing this ?

EDIT: on the app's Google console page, I see a Security alert:

> Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns. Please see
>   this Google Help Center article for details.

Could this be a reason for Google to remove the app, even after the APK went Live ?

Comment: Are you seeing the app not found page like this link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.notfound
You can even replace the package name with your app's package name to be sure that it is not there on playstore.

Comment: Indeed, I see the "app not found" page when I open the url with our app id

Comment: in that case, before removing your app from playstore directly. Google would have sent you a warning e-mail or notification inside the playstore dashboard.
Check if you've missed any warning from Google team.

Comment: same problem here!

Comment: Do you see the alert "Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns" on your app console page ?

Comment: Same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031054/my-app-disappeared-from-play-store-even-its-still-published-in-developer-cons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a problem on Google's end this morning.

I have been experiencing similar issues this morning.  Our developer portal showed all apps as published and I hadn't released any updates for several months.  However, none of my users could find the app when searching the Play Store and you would see an error when you tried to access it (via direct link).  I did not get any emails, alerts, notifications, or security warnings.  It seemed like the app had just vanished.

My guess is that there is some kind of outage or issue on Google's end.  Many developers have reported similar behavior this morning.

[Exhibit A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60490757/my-app-in-google-play-store-was-disappeared-google-play-store#60490757)

[Exhibit B](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/fccktn/apps_missing_on_playstore_no_emails_or_warnings/)

I solved this problem by going to the Play Store Console and changing a line in my app description and submitting.  I just added one period and clicked submit update and now it feels like everything has gone back to normal.  You could give that a try and hopefully that helps.  I am still unsure why this happened in the first place and I cannot find any news or announcements from Google.

Comment: Your solution worked! after a minor edition of the description, the app is back on the store. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities for this.
It might not be an error and might simply be a short time during which the updates, after review, are going live.
The most basic one is an error during publishing. Perhaps you specified incorrect settings for the availability within your country. Review this in the developer console.
Secondly, perhaps in the update, you upgraded the target API version to a version higher than that of the device you're using. It would not be visible on the play store on your device in that scenario. Try checking on various devices, and even the play store web portal.
Another issue could be that your app breached google's terms of service and in that case, you should check for an email informing you of the same. These are just the main possibilities.
Other errors can be troubleshot from the [support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9042516?hl=en)
If all else fails, raise an issue with the google play support team.

Comment: The latest APK has already been reviewed and went live 5 days ago, so if there was an issue with min SDK requirements or breaching google's terms of service, the APK would not have gone live. Also, we have not received any warning email from Google Play...

Answer (score 0):

My app showed up after a couple of hours without having to make any update.
I did email support though - but haven't received feedback.