# My app in google play store was disappeared google play store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Currently, my application disappeared from google play store.
In spite of previously being available.

> - There is no app update.
> - No warning dialog.
> - No configuration change.
> - No warning email.
> - Status in google play console "Published and All updates are live 6 days ago"
>
> google play search result:  `We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.`
>
> Is there any issues or any suggestions ?

Comment: Check your gmail.

Comment: If its removed you will the the mail with reason , you can even check the reason on play store

Comment: It generally wont get auto removed 95% of time , If there is problem with app it wont even get published

Comment: there is no email and warning dialog in google play console

Answer (score 0):

So actually, when you publish an app or update, they let you know how long the review process should take before your changes can go live. If your update is taking longer than they have estimated and you still haven’t seen your changes on Google Play, troubleshoot your specific issue below.

for more info you can see in the website:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9042516?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

the application is probably waiting for approval

Comment: I did not update any thing what kind of approval ?.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Google bug. Re-post the application. This will help.